# How to Dynamically Specify Class Labels in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

Let me begin by giving a generic example of the dataset form factor I am expecting in my code.
**Thanks @Sathish for helping me with representing this.**

```
attribute1 <- c("str1", "str2", "strN")
attribute2 <- c("num1", "num2", "numN")
attributeN <- c("val1", "val2", "valN")
class <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE || FALSE)

df <- data.frame(attribute1, attribute2, attributeN, class)

dput(df)
print(df)
```

The class doesn't necessarily need to be boolean. I just used it in this example for simplicity's sake.

I am trying to create a reusable ANN (Artificial Neural Network) in `R` which can work with any .csv given that the dataset conforms to certain criteria. One big issue I have is that I can't seem to figure out how to dynamically split the data with something like `createDataPartition()` from `library(caret)`:

```
data <- createDataPartition(dataset$lapply(dataset[ncol(dataset)]), p = test_ratio, list = FALSE)
```

Here is what I've attempted most recently to try to solve the above code snippet. Note that `fread()` is from `library(data.table)`:

```
library(caret)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
dataset <- as.data.frame(fread(file = file_name), header = TRUE)
class_label <- lapply(dataset[ncol(dataset)], function(x) names(dataset[ncol(dataset)]))
data <- createDataPartition('$'(dataset, class_label), p = test_ratio, list = FALSE)
```

The class label is expected to be the last column in any dataset. It seems to me that `createDataPartition()` is a bit static since it looks for `Data$Class` to be distinguished in that specific way. But, I am still learning R so I could be missing something. I've looked in several places to find an answer, but I couldn't find anything concrete.

So I think the root of my problem here is that I'm not sure how to pass the name of the class label to `Data$Class` with `lapply()`. What I've tried gives me this error:

> Error in createDataPartition(dataset$class_name,  p = test_ratio, list
> = FALSE) :   y must have at least 2 data points Calls: get_stratified_samples -> createDataPartition Execution halted

I think I understand the error but can't seem to figure out how to go about the solution. I believe it is because `lapply(dataset[ncol(dataset)], function(x) names(dataset[ncol(dataset)]))` portion gives me a string of the class label name instead of the class label itself?

Also, another one I'd like to do is use `createDataPartition()`, or a function similar to it, to stratified split the data based on multiple classes. This too has eluded me.

Let me know if I need to add anymore details, and I'll do my best.

Comment: @Sathish, you are right. I updated the question with the correct information. I'm adding a generic table which would be in the form of the .csv data I am looking for. It's pretty basic from my understanding.

Comment: Thanks for all your help in framing my question @Sathish. There's a portion you wrote that I don't really understand. `df$X. <- NULL
df$X..1 <- NULL
df$X..2 <- NULL
df$X..3 <- NULL
dput(df)`

Comment: Exactly. I'm trying to stratified split the data based on the last column which is expected to be the class label without needing to know the class label name ahead of time.

Comment: So the `df$X..1` refers to the first column of the data frame? Also, `df$X.` is a bit confusing for me. What is it referring to?

Comment: Yes. Stratified split is a split where the ratio of column values from the original dataset are retained in both the resulting training and testing samples. That's the expected outcome I'm looking for.

Comment: Sorry @Sathish, I had a meeting to attend for class. You're fine. Don't stay any longer than you want. You've been a tremendous help with not just my question, but R in general. I'm still in the meeting so I can't work on this at the moment, but I will update my question as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [help page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-86/topics/createDataPartition) for `createDataPartition`, the argument for y should be a "a vector of outcomes" . I have no clue what you are trying to do with these lines of code:

```
class_label <- lapply(dataset[ncol(dataset)], function(x) names(dataset[ncol(dataset)]))
data <- createDataPartition('$'(dataset, class_name), p = test_ratio, list = FALSE)
```

If you want to pass a column of a dataframe to this function dynamically, you can use the column name, or the column number:

```
splitData = function(dataset,Col,test_ratio){

      createDataPartition(dataset[,Col],p=test_ratio)

}
```

So for example in iris:

```
splitData(iris , "Species",0.7)
$Resample1
  [1]   2   3   4   5   7   8   9  11  13  16  17  18  19  20  22  23  24  25
 [19]  26  27  28  29  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  39  40  42  48  49  50  52
 [37]  53  54  55  56  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  68  69  70  74  75  76  77
 [55]  78  79  80  81  83  87  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 102 104
 [73] 106 108 110 111 112 113 114 115 117 118 119 120 121 123 124 125 128 129
 [91] 130 132 135 136 137 138 139 141 142 143 144 146 147 149 150
```

Or the last column of the dataframe:

```
splitData(iris ,ncol(iris),0.7)
$Resample1
  [1]   5   6   9  11  12  13  15  16  17  18  19  21  22  24  26  27  28  29
 [19]  31  32  34  35  36  38  39  40  41  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51
 [37]  52  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  73  74
 [55]  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  87  89  92  95  98  99 100 101 102
 [73] 104 105 106 107 108 110 114 115 116 118 119 121 122 123 125 127 128 129
 [91] 131 132 133 134 135 137 138 140 141 143 144 146 148 149 150
```

Comment: `class_name` is supposed to be `class_label` here. Sorry about that. The goal of this code was to find the class label dynamically which is expected to be the last column of the dataset. Then I wanted to use that in `createDataPartition()` so that I could create partitions for any dataset as input for the code. So one dataset may have a class label called 'class' or it could be 'outcome' or 'category' etc. I was wanting my code to not care about the actual class label name in the provided dataset. It was to only need to look at the last column to know the class label name.

Comment: The problem was that when I attempted to pass the variable `class_label` to, for example, `dataset$class_label`, the code would try to look for a column called 'class_label` instead of applying the value of the `class_label` variable. So then I tried using `$` as a function which it already is, but you can do it like `'$'(data, col)`. When I used `'$'(dataset, class_label)`, it would do the same thing where it would look for a column called 'class_label' instead of applying the value of the `class_label` variable.

Comment: Actually, my problem could have been the fact that I had `class_label` as the variable but was accidentally trying to use `class_name` as the variable. I will try it out when I get an opportunity to. Thanks for pointing that out.